# Problema com modificação de uma lista dentro de uma funçao (python)

Tags: python

```
def f(i):
    return i + 2
def g(i):
    return i > 5
def aplicacao(L, f, g):    
    lista_f = [f(i) for i in L]
    lista_g = [g(i) for i in lista_f]
    L = [L[k] for k in range(len(L)) if lista_g[k] == True]    
    if len(L) == 0:
        return -1
    else:    
        return L      
    
L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
print(aplicacao(L, f, g))
```

A função aplicacao(L, f, g) recebe uma lista L como parâmetro e aplica as funções f e g, retornando uma nova lista L com certos valores que depende resultado de f e g.

Minha dúvida está relacionada ao print. Quando eu faço **print(aplicacao(L, f, g))** eu obtenho
**[0, -10, 5, 6, -4]**, ou seja, o input original, sem que a função tenha modificado a minha lista.
Porém, quando eu reescrevi uma outra função mais simples, por exemplo:

```
def func(l):
    return l.append(5)
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
func(l)
print(l)
```

Eu obtive uma lista modificada, nesse caso **[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]**.

Alguém conseguiria me explicar o porquê? Obrigado.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema modificando a linha `L = [L[k] for k in range(len(L)) if lista_g[k] == True]`  para `L[:] = [L[k] for k in range(len(L)) if lista_g[k] == True]`. Aparentemente assim eu estou substituindo os _elementos_ da lista L. Porém, mesmo assim eu não consigo entender porque isso funciona.

Answer (score 2):

**Passagem de parâmetros por valor ou por referência**

O termo “parâmetro” é usado para indicar os nomes entre parênteses existentes na declaração da função. Já o termo “argumento” se refere às variáveis ou aos valores literais passados quando uma linha de código chama a função.

É muito comum ver programadores usando somente o termo “parâmetro”, sem todo esse rigor científico.

Para facilitar, nessa resposta, vou usar o termo “parâmetro” para indicar as duas coisas.

Nas linguagens de programação, a passagem de parâmetros ocorre por valor ou por referência. Algumas linguagens apresentam outras formas, mas todas acabam sendo uma combinação desses dois tipos.

Se a passagem é por valor, uma cópia da variável original é passada para a função. Mesmo que o valor do parâmetro seja alterado dentro da função, o valor original (fora da função) não foi alterado quando a função termina de executar.

Se a passagem é por referência, uma referência ao endereço de memória da variável original é passada para a função. Assim, qualquer alteração no valor do parâmetro dentro da função se torna permanente na variável original, mesmo depois que a função termina.

Em Python, a passagem de parâmetros é feita por valor, mas… em Python, tudo é um objeto.

Por isso, o valor passado para a função não é o valor do objeto, mas uma cópia da referência ao objeto, que fica no *call stack* (pilha de execução).

Você não precisa entender como esse gerenciamento de memória funciona agora. Só precisa saber que, **caso você tente alterar o valor do objeto dentro da função, uma nova referência é criada dentro da função e a ligação com o objeto original é perdida.**

Veja esse exemplo:

```
def mudar(numero, lista):
    numero = 5
    lista = ['nova']
    print('1 - ', numero)
    print('2 - ', lista)

n = 1
l = ['original']
mudar(n, l)
print('3 - ', n)
print('4 - ', l)
```

A função `mudar()` recebe uma referência para os objetos n e l nos parâmetros `numero` e `lista`. Em seguida, a função muda os valores desses parâmetros.

No entanto, a ligação com os objetos originais é perdida nesse momento e os valores originais são preservados. Isso é percebido quando a função termina de executar.

O resultado é o seguinte:

```
1 -  5
2 -  ['nova']
3 -  1
4 -  ['original']
```

Parece complicado, mas é fácil de entender se você considerar o seguinte:

**Dentro de uma função, o objeto original nunca pode receber uma nova atribuição, ou seja, ele não pode ser substituído. Qualquer tentativa de modificar o valor de um objeto passado como parâmetro dentro de uma função resulta na criação de um novo objeto.**

*Então nunca é possível modificar o conteúdo de um objeto passado para uma função?*

É sim, mas sem substituir o objeto original.

Isso significa que, se o objeto for imutável, como uma string, um inteiro ou uma tupla, o valor original do objeto antes da chamada não pode ser alterado dentro da função.

Mas se o objeto for mutável, como uma lista ou um dicionário, é possível **modificar os itens dentro do objeto** na função. O objeto continuará sendo o mesmo, mas com o estado alterado após a execução da função.

Veja como, nesse exemplo:

```
def acrescentar(numero, lista):
    numero += 5
    lista.append('novo item')

n = 1
l = ['original']
acrescentar(n, l)
print(n)
print(l)
```

A função `acrescentar()` soma 5 ao valor do número passado. Nesse momento, ao tentar alterar o valor de um objeto imutável (int), um novo objeto é criado, com o valor 6. Esse objeto é perdido quando a função termina.

Já no caso da lista, não há uma nova atribuição para a variável, mas sim uma alteração da lista original, usando a função `append()` para acrescentar um elemento.

Essa modificação é possível e se torna permanente, mesmo depois que a função termina.

O resultado desse programa é o seguinte:

```
1
['original', 'novo item']
```

A alteração da lista dentro da função, vista nesse último exemplo, é conhecida na programação como **Efeito Colateral**.

Isso quer dizer que a função não realizou só uma tarefa computacional e retornou um valor. Ela deixou o sistema em um estado diferente do que ele estava antes da função ser executada.

No caso do seu programa, é isso o que está acontecendo. Na linha:

```
L = [L[k] for k in range(len(L)) if lista_g[k] == True]
```

você substitui a referência à variável `L` dentro da função. Por isso, o valor da lista L fora da função permanece o mesmo.

O `print()` no final do seu código original até funciona, porque você retorna a variável L modificada na função. No entanto, você não sobrepõe a variável L original com esse resultado. Ele só é impresso e depois é perdido.

Uma solução simples e rápida seria atribuir o retorno da função a L. Em vez de:

```
L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
print(aplicacao(L, f, g))
```

Você poderia fazer:

```
L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
L = aplicacao(L, f, g)
print(L)
```

> L[:] = [L[k] for k in range(len(L)) if lista_g[k] == True].
> Aparentemente assim eu estou substituindo os elementos da lista L.

Sim, você está atribuindo a compreensão de lista do lado direito a uma fatia da lista L. Nesse caso, como não informou os índices inicial e final, a fatia corresponde à lista inteira.

Para não gerar confusão, você pode simplificar a função `aplicacao()`, retornando o valor esperado sem essa atribuição à variável original. Por exemplo:

```
def aplicacao(L, f, g):    
    lista_f = [f(i) for i in L]
    lista_g = [g(i) for i in lista_f]
    return [L[k] for k in range(len(L)) if lista_g[k] == True] or -1
```

Dessa forma fica claro que a lista passada só é usada para o processamento e o valor retornado precisa ser atribuído a uma variável no código que chama a função.

Espero ter ajudado.

Fonte: Adaptado de https://vaiprogramar.com/como-declarar-uma-funcao-em-python/#parametros_funcao. Acesso em 6/7/2020.